# How to fix weird lighting in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

So I am currently working on a project in Unity, trying to learn the basics of it. I'm trying to create a room that is only lit by some lamps, but I keep getting these weird lights inside the room that's supposed to be dark.

I tried setting the Environment Light to None, but this issue still happens.

Comment: Add some screenshots to illustate the problem. Include the scene heirarchy and lighting settings.

Comment: Which Render Pipeline are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove directional lights from your scene.
- Under `Window > Rendering > Lighting > Environment` remove the `Skybox material` and set `Ambient Color` to black.
- In the same tab under `Other Settings` disable `Fog`.